# Magento stock getting overwritten to 0 on some products

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I'm seeing an issue in our Magento 1.5.0.1 store where the stock is getting overwritten to 0 on some products.  This seems to be happening automatically and I can't figure out why.  I recently installed Lightspeed and SpeedBooster from Tinybrick, which may have something to do with it, but I have since disabled them and still no luck.  I'm really at a loss here, so any thoughts, ideas, or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

### Backtrace Data

```
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): before save, QTY is 0 for 615906-2PK...printing backtrace
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [21] VPS_Stock_Model_Observer::catalog_product_save_before LINE 1265 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [20] Mage_Core_Model_App::_callObserverMethod LINE 1246 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [19] Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent LINE 416 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/Mage.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [18] Mage::dispatchEvent LINE 391 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [17] Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave LINE 306 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [16] Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave LINE 474 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [15] Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::_beforeSave LINE 316 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [14] Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save LINE 114 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item/Api.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [13] Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item_Api::update LINE  ()
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [12] ::call_user_func_array LINE 404 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [11] Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::multiCall LINE  ()
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [10] SoapServer::handle LINE 832 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [9] Zend_Soap_Server::handle LINE 145 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [8] Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap::run LINE 76 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [7] Mage_Api_Model_Server::run LINE 42 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/controllers/IndexController.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [6] Mage_Api_IndexController::indexAction LINE 418 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [5] Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::dispatch LINE 253 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [4] Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match LINE 176 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [3] Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch LINE 340 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [2] Mage_Core_Model_App::run LINE 627 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/app/Mage.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): [1] Mage::run LINE 80 (/chroot/home/valuepet/valuepetsupplies.com/html/index.php)
2011-09-29T18:10:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): END BACKTRACE
```

Comment: It seems to be happening at regular intervals, so I'm leaning towards a cron job, but I still don't know which one or why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a before and after save event listener on the product and stock objects.

Have the listener check for a stock of "0".

If a stock of zero is detected, construct a stack trace via the information in `debug_backtrace`.  You'll want to manually create this, as a circular reference in  a backtrace's paramaters can potentially create infinite output.

Use the backtrace to determine where/when the stock is getting set to zero.

Comment: thank you, that helps.  I have done that, but I can't seem to make heads or tails of the data.  I have added a backtrace from the log to my initial question.  Perhaps I'm not printing out the right data or not doing something correctly, but it doesn't seem to tell me what caused the save to happen...just that it DID happen.

Comment: Based on the debugging information it looks like Magento is receiving a SOAP API call from somewhere (the update method) that's sending through a stock update request. That means your problem isn't Magento, it's that this script is updating the stock to "0".  Track down all your soap scripts, or turn off API access (and wait to see what breaks ;) )

Comment: You're absolutely right!  I came to that conclusion at about the same time and have since determined that it was in fact a bug in the Salesforce integration.  Thanks for your help!  And great trick on the backtrace...that led me to the answer!